# Superb Undeniably Awesome Legend!

Tags: riddle, pattern, rhyme, knowledge, steganography

> Never try to ignore, b'lieve in the pentagonal head of mine.
>   It gives you my first three, out of nine.
>
> As a rightful person, look and say to my face.
>   Three of these and thrice more, completes your half a race.
>
> Rammle is what you've found. Now get the squares off my back.
>   Earn three more and you have left nine more to crack.
>
> An ultimate, lazy and outspoken Mr.Caterer, who lives on my thighs.
>   Force him to give you the next three, if he denies.
>
> Jantar Mantar all above, while the headless famous lives on my feet,
>   Three again and seek three from the first of the rest and you shall tribute me and cherish this amazing feat!

**Reveal the name of a legend hidden within the rhyme**

**Hint**

> Use Mathematics!

Comment: Maybe we'll need a hint at this point... I'm thinking to a Hindu deity or a famous Indian person, but that's all I got...

Comment: @IAmInPLS Hint!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is:

> [Srinivasa Ramanujan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan)

*-Explanations*-

> Consider the riddle as a person. So, it stated head, face, back, thighs, feet and the rest which means:
>  Head = Title
>  Face = first Two Lines
>  Back = next Two Lines
>  Thighs = next Two Lines
>  Feet = next Two Lines
>  Rest = rest of the Lines

Also,

> There are patterns like pentagonal, squares, lazy caterer, fibonacci, look and say in the riddle. The words jantar and mantar (or yantra and mantra) means [calculation instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jantar_Mantar)

Never try to ignore, b'lieve in the pentagonal head of mine.
It gives you my first three, out of nine.

> First we need to take the [pentagonal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number) out of the title, which is the *head* of the riddle. So, we take the letters 1, 5 and 12. We get: **s**, **r**, **i**

As a rightful person, look and say to my face.
Three of these and thrice more, completes your half a race.

> Then, we use the [look-and-say sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence) on the *face* of the riddle, which is composed of the first two lines. We get: **n**, **i**, **v**

Rammle is what you've found. Now get the squares off my back.
Earn three more and you have left nine more to crack.

> Now, we take the squares off your *back*, which is the next two lines: **a**, **s**, **a**

We have the first part, yay!

**Second Part**

An ultimate, lazy and outspoken Mr.Caterer, who lives on my thighs.
Force him to give you the next three, if he denies.

> We first use the [lazy caterer's sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_caterer%27s_sequence) on the *thighs*: so we take the letters 1, 2, 4 from the line *Rammle is what you've found...*, so we obtain the letters **r**, **a**, **m**

Jantar Mantar all above, while the headless famous lives on my feet,

> Then the *headless famous* refers to the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), without the first term (*headless*). So, we get the letters 1, 2 and 3 which gives us **a**, **n**, **u**.

Three again and seek three from the first of the rest and you shall tribute me and cherish this amazing feat!

> Finally, we *seek three from the first of the rest*, that's to say we just need to take the first three letters of the last sentence (*Jantar Mantar all above...*), which gives us **j**, **a**, **n**

And we get it all together to have the final answer! Complex but cool riddle!